# World texture with stars and constellations

Tags: texturing, shaders, world

I have seen many exames on how to create a night sky in blender. However, all of them deal with scattered bright dots on a black background.

My question is: is there an available sky texture image with stars forming actual constellations?

I have seen many images for texturing sphere to fake Earth, moon, etc. What about the sky?

Thank you?

Comment: What it sounds like you need is an HDRI.  HDRI's are 360 degree images that blender will put into your world and implement all the lighting from the image onto your scene, as well as providing reflections from the HDRI background.  To add an HDRI to your blender environment, first, download one from an online site such as > https://hdrihaven.com/ <  Next, in your blender scene, go the the world properties tab on the left, click on the color property, and change it to environment texture.  Now all you need to do is open the image, and go into rendered view to see it.  I hope this helped!

Comment: NASA has some super highres images of the night sky. It does not get more realistic than this! Sorry I forgot the link but you should be able to find them easily.

Comment: I think the link Bruno mentioned is this - https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4851